Is this PDE describing the variable length cable dynamics right?
I am solving a variable length cable-Mass dynamics and having some problem. Here is the problem description:

I noticed that this post is off-topic, while I found a related paper about this question, so I will post the link to the paper rather than extending the result. Other user may get benefits from this.
related paper


Consider a cable connecting a mass and wrounded in a winch. The initial length of cable is $L$, one side of cable is wrounded in a winch, which is rotating at velocity $v(t)$, the other side of cable is connecting to a mass $M$. The schematic figure is shown below:

Assuming that the parts of the cable wound around the winch are not taken into account, then how should we build a dynamic model of the cable and the mass system?

Symbols:

The cable Young modulus of cable is $E$
cross-section area is $A$
line density is $m$.


My prior solution is in this way:
take coordinate system as shown below:

The vibration equation is:
$$
\begin{aligned}EA\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}&=m\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}\\EAu^{\prime}\left(0,t\right)&=M\ddot{u}\left(0,t\right)+c\dot{u}\left(0,t\right)+ku\left(0,t\right)\\\dot{u}\left(x_l,t\right)&=v,\quad x_l=L-\int_0^tv\mathrm{d}t\end{aligned}
$$
The problem is:

Is this equation right?
If right, how to solve this equation?


some extened thought: Heat transfer during welding
The torch nozzle is moving in the molten pool, and the heat source is moving at this time, which gives a similar heat transfer function?

